# Is there a generally accepted way to pass data from one ASP.Net form to another after validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net form (Page1) where the user enters some data and then clicks the submit button.

As part of Page1, I have some Validators, including a CustomValidator which needs to do its validation back on the server.

When the user clicks the submit button a post is done to Page1 and the validation routine is run on the server and as long as I check Page.IsValid in the button click routine the form knows whether things have passed or not.

When the validation doesn't pass everything properly goes back to Form1 and the error message is displayed.

When the form does pass validation, I want to pass the data that the user entered to a second form (Page2) so that Page2 can be rendered correctly based on the data the user entered on Page1.

Is there a generally accepted way, or best way, to pass the data to Page2?  Here are some ways I know about:

- Call Page2 with a query string:  This won't work as I need the data to not be visible to the user in certain cases.
- Use the PostBackUrl on the submit button to go to Page2:  As far as I know, this won't work correctly because then the server side validation routines for Page1 won't be run.
- Use Session Variables:  I don't know of a particular reason why this would be bad.
- Use Server.Transfer:  I don't really have any experience with this.

I would think that this would be a pretty standard thing to do but I'm having a hard time finding any information on the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a form of secondary storage for this data, using either `Session` storage or `Server.Transfer` would work.

You might find `Server.Transfer` is a little neater as, this way, you'll retain your POST values across the transfer. This will potentially save you a lot of cumbersome code playing around with session state, which, depending on how complex your forms are, could open the way to all kinds of unusual behaviour that you'd have to predict and plan to deal with in advance such as what happens when a user clicks the "back" button or - if you're posting across multiple pages - what happens when a session expires (plus Servy's examples of having multiple tabs open on the same page(s), all sharing the same session). Working with session state can be messy.

Perform your validation on PostBack then, if `Page.IsValid`, do:

```
Server.Transfer("/FormPage2.aspx");
```

`Server.Transfer` preserves `Request.QueryString` and `Request.Form`, so you can pick up your POST values on `FormPage2` and do whatever you need with them here - whether it be using them for conditional logic or rendering them out again as hidden fields to join them up with the values from the second page of the form (bear in mind that if you're doing this you'll have to revalidate the hidden inputs at this stage).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx

I have used session state for handling complex forms in the past and found myself wishing I'd used `Server.Transfer`, which I plan to use for all similar endeavours in the future, unless I have a very good reason not to.

You might also consider using a [multiview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx), but in my experience these can be very messy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edited with some additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Session` object is a standard way to pass information across forms.

@Servy gives a good explaination (in the comments below) on how Server.Transfer *can* help you in this case.

The other options you stated all have problems, just like you mentioned...

If you want to use Session:
In the postback of Page1 you can set the values:

```
Session["myVar"] = <Data you want to pass to page2>
```

In page2 in the OnLoad:

```
if (Session["myVar"] != null)
{
   myVar = Session["MyVar"]
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say session is preferred.  When making any website always strive to keep it stateless, as much as possible.  Problems include consumption of lots of memory for long periods of time on the server; improper behavior when a user has multiple tabs/windows of the site open; it's possible to end up in an invalid state if you try to "start over" or otherwise quit the expected flow early, or use back/forward to jump around.  Oh, and `Server.Transfer` could be a great solution to this problem.  It's basically #1 but without allowing the end user to see the query parameters.

Comment: @Servy Server.Transfer with a long QueryString? vs Strong-Typed objects in a Session? I can't see why that is better

Comment: See edited comment.  In any case it's clearly a valid option; you say it couldn't be used, and it clearly can be.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest solution would be to specify a PreviousPageType directive. It specifies a type that the page should expect to receive and you would do a normal POST to that page.

On the second page of your application, use the following directive:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/FirstPage.aspx" %>
```

You will be able to access the properties exposed and check for validity by using something like this:

```
if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsValid)
```

Comment: I do a similar thing implementing a search function on the master page to the search results page. The search button has PostBackUrl to the search page. Search page uses PreviousPage.Master to get the search string. PreviousPageType directive wasn't needed.

Comment: That's correct, but while the PreviousPageType directive wasn't needed, it will give you the ability to use the properties on the PreviousPage object without having to typecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Server.Transfer by adding a property to your page1. In your second page in page_load for example:

```
Page1 prev = Page.PreviousPage as Page1;
if (prev != null)
{
    // access your property here and set up the page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Server.Transfer` can safely receive a query string without fear of the user seeing it.

Instead of `Session` use `Context.Items`.

```
Context.Items["validationProblems"] = "...";
Server.Transfer("FixProblems.aspx");
```

My other comment is that in my experience it's more "standard" to keep the validation UI contained in the same form that's collecting the information.  This enables "real time" feedback.  In practice I think it's better to give a user information that their doing something wrong as early as possible.

Note, that's just in my experience though.. it's a big world.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more that you presently require, but one alternative is to save the data in a database:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-set-up-the-sql-membership-provider